# Change @Input field of @Component after sending an Http Request (Angular2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, observable

I am working on an `Angular2` application and one of the `@Components` has a button that when clicked will send a `post` request to my server which will either respond with an `Ok(string)` or a `BadRequest(string)`.

I am having trouble updating an @Input field of one of my @Components after getting the answer from the server.

Below are simplified version of some of my classes.

### My Component class

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'model-comp',
    templateUrl: './model.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./model.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent{
    @Input() model: Model;
    @Output() emitter: EventEmitter<Model> = new EventEmitter<Model>();

    public constructor(private service: MyService){}

    public toggle(): void {
        this.service.send(model.id, model.name){
            .subscribe(
                result  => this.onSuccess(result)),
                error   => this.onError(error),
                ()      => this.onComplete());
    }

    public onSuccess(result: string): void {
        if(result.inculdes("Some Text")) this.model.flag = true;
        else this.model.flag = false;
        this.emitter.emit(this.model);
    }

    public onError(error: any): void {
        //notification using bootstrap-notify
    }

    public onComplete(): void {
        //currently empty
    }
}
```

### My Service class

```
export class MyService{

    public send(id: string, name: string){
        return <Observable<string>>this.http
            .post('url', new Dto(id, name))
            .map(result => this.getData<string>(result))
            .catch(this.catchBadResponse);
    }

    private getData<E>(result: Response): E {
        //checking if result.status is ok
        var body = result.json ? res.json(): null;
        return  <E>(body || {});
    }

    private catchBadRespomse: (error: any) => Observable<any> = (error: any) => {
        var response = <Response>error;
        var json = response.json();
        var msg = json.Message;
        var errormsg = json?
            (json.error ? json.error: JSON.stringify(msg?msg:json)) :
            (response.statusText || 'Error?');
        return Obserable.of(errormsg);
    }

}
```

### Template of MyComponent

```
<button (click)="toggle()"
[ngClass]="{'class1': true, 'class2': model.flag}">Text</button>
```

### Template of Parent Component

```
<div *ngFor="let model of getList()">
    <model-comp [model]="model" (emitter)="onEmit($event)"></model-comp>
</div>
```

### The `onEmit` Function

```
onEmit(evt: any): void{
    if(evt instanceof Model){
        var evtModel = evt as Model;
        this.list.find(search => search.id == evtModel.id)
            .isFav = evtModel.isFav;
    }
}
```

The problem is that even though I post my data and receive the response, The property `flag` of my `model` does not change.

I think that the click event reloads the component thus removing the observers of the `EventEmitter`.

So is there any way to cancel the reload, not lose the observers of the `EventEmitter` or any other way to update the root object or the element class?

Comment: If you have an input and output that belong together you should name it like `@Input() model:Model;` and `@Output() modelChange:EventEmitter<Model> = ...` then you can use "two-way" binding like `[(model)]="someProp"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer does it matter how I name the output field?

Comment: Names always matter ;-) If it's about the same property then they should be named according to the schema I mentioned. Just a hint - not related to your actual issue.

Comment: Why would the subscription reload the component? I don't think this is the case. Why do you think the the `model.flag` is not changed - because the `class2` is not added?

Comment: Can you try to add a button like `<button (click)="model.flag = !model.flag">click me</button>` and check if this results in the expected behavior?

Comment: What do you need the `emitter` for?

Comment: Your parent component doesn't seem to use `flag` in any way.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It doesn't but as I stated in the question after the click event, the component gets refreshed ( not sure why ) thus the change in the flag gets lost. So essentially if i call this `this.emitter.emit(this.model);` from the `toggle()` the class gets updated, if I call it from the `onSuccess()` then nothing happens.

Comment: What does the `onEmit()` method do? I suspect it is causing the problem.

Comment: The code in `onEmit` doesn't seem to update `list` but the whole method seems pointless because it looks for the passed model and then updates it but to me it looks liky they are the same instances anyway, therefor it sets `isFav` to the value it already has anyway.

Comment: What is `getList()` doing?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The getList() returns a new list ( the objects of the list have more info that the component requires so I remove the unnecessary parts ).

Comment: Tha't basically what my answer tells already. If `getList()` returns a new list every time it is called, `*ngFor` will be permanently busy rerendering the items. Using method/function calls in the view is strongly discouraged. Rather assing the list to a field and bind to that field instead of the method.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So i should make it a field and initialize it in `ngOnInit()` ?

Comment: `ngOnInit()` is fine, you can also assign a new list later if there is a reason, but just don't bind to a method that returns a new list every time it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update** (see comments below the question)

If `getList()` (what `*ngFor` binds to) returns a new list every time it is called, `*ngFor` will be permanently busy rerendering the items because change detection will cause `getList()` being called again and again.

Binding to a function that returns a new object or array every time it's called directly will cause serious issues like exceptions and dramatic performance degredation.

Using method/function calls in the view is strongly discouraged in general. Rather assign the list to a field and bind to that field instead of the method.

`ngOnInit()` is fine for initializing the list but also any event handler for initializing or updating the list.

**original**

If you modify the `model` value that you got passed in from the parent, then the parent also sees the change. Emitting the value as an event is probably redundant.

I guess you are modifying `list` (from `<div *ngFor="let model of list">`) in `onEmit()` which then causes `*ngFor` to rerender the list.

Comment: I can't imagine this to work. The syntax in your version doesn't make any sense. I'm not entirely sure whether `class1` and `class2` need the `'`. I assumed they are only required in Dart but I might have mixed something up. But I'm sure the `=` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should change @input property from within the component.
it suppose to listen and act to changes from the parent component.

Comment: So is there any way to change the model of the parent component? Or a way to add/remove the class of the button?

Comment: absolutely, you should read this: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html#creating-custom-two-way-data-bindings

Comment: Not quite sure where I should use the 2 way data binding? Could you add it to your answer? Should I add it like `<my-comp [(model)] = "model.subModel"></my-comp>` ?

Comment: exactly. the parent push data to the child component and listen to changes coming from the child component.

Comment: I tried using an `EventEmitter` but the observers get removed when I call emit in the `onSuccess()` method (works when called from the `toggle` but it's kinda useless there).

Answer (score 0):

MyComponent.ts

```
export class MyComponent{
    @Input() model: Model;
    //@Output() emitter: EventEmitter<Model> = new EventEmitter<Model>();

    public constructor(private service: MyService){}

    public toggle(): void {
        this.service.send(model.id, model.name){
            .subscribe(
                result  => this.onSuccess(result)),
                error   => this.onError(error),
                ()      => this.onComplete());
    }

    public onSuccess(result: string): void {
        if(result.inculdes("Some Text")) this.model.flag = true;
        else this.model.flag = false;
        //this.emitter.emit(this.model);
        this.service.emitter.next(false);
    }

    public onError(error: any): void {
        //notification using bootstrap-notify
    }

    public onComplete(): void {
        //currently empty
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Injectable // important
export class MyService{
    public emitter: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    public send(id: string, name: string){
        return <Observable<string>>this.http
            .post('url', new Dto(id, name))
            .map(result => this.getData<string>(result))
            .catch(this.catchBadResponse);
    }

    private getData<E>(result: Response): E {
        //checking if result.status is ok
        var body = result.json ? res.json(): null;
        return  <E>(body || {});
    }

    private catchBadRespomse: (error: any) => Observable<any> = (error: any) => {
        var response = <Response>error;
        var json = response.json();
        var msg = json.Message;
        var errormsg = json?
            (json.error ? json.error: JSON.stringify(msg?msg:json)) :
            (response.statusText || 'Error?');
        return Obserable.of(errormsg);
    }

}
```

Now you can listen to `Service.emitter` anywhere in app

Comment: Pretty sure it should be `@Injectable()`

Comment: It worked with [Günter Zöchbauer Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188921/change-input-field-of-component-after-sending-an-http-request-angular2/41220354#41220354)